# Double Tap/ double click Angular2 & ionic

Tags: angular, ionic2, directive, angular2-directives, double-click

I am searching on many forums and questions, but nobody seems to ask how to double click ou double tap in Angular/ionic 2 ?

In ionic v1 it was available with `on-double-tap` (see http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/onDoubleTap/)

**Does anyone maybe have a tip or any code to catch double click events on ionic 2 / angular 2?**

Maybe through HammerJS?

Thank you very much ! 
Luis :)

Comment: not sure of double click.. but I think you could consider [press event](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/components/#gestures)

Comment: I found it.. relatively easy : (dblclick)="myFunction()" from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOM_events#Events :)

Comment: ok.. not really sure how it would be useful in mobile device

Comment: That's because you maybe don't know my application ? (dblclick) works on mobile, I tested.

Comment: ok..fair enough :)

Comment: Haha thank you anyway ! Bye :)

Comment: Any solution for this now? dblclick doesn't work inside of ionic

Answer (score 26, accepted):

So after 1-2 hours it was obvious, you don't need to catch double click events with Ionic, but with pure **JavaScript**: `dblclick()`

So in Angular 2 it would be: `(dblclick)="myFunction()"` and that's it!

Here you will find other events for [JavaScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOM_events#Events).

Comment: Inorder for a generic implementation irrespective of the platform we need to write a custom directive of our own.

Answer (score 7):

html file

```
<button (tap)="tapEvent()">Tap Me!</button>
```

ts file

```
let count : number = 0;
tapEvent(){
this.count++;
setTimeout(() => {
  if (this.count == 1) {
    this.count = 0;
    alert('Single Tap');
  }if(this.count > 1){
    this.count = 0;
    alert('Double Tap');
  }
}, 250);
```

}

Answer (score 4):

To catch the double click event, the following can be used:

```
(dblclick)="clickFunction()"
```

If we want to fire a function on click and onother function on double click we can use the following:

```html
<button (click)="simpleClickFunction()" (dblclick)="doubleClickFunction()">click me!</button>
```

However, the `simpleClickFunction` function will be called also when `doubleClickFunction` is fired. To prevent it to happen, `setTimeout` can help as the following:

`html template`

```html
<button (click)="simpleClickFunction()" (dblclick)="doubleClickFunction()">click me!</button>
```

`Component`

```js
simpleClickFunction(): void{
    this.timer = 0;
    this.preventSimpleClick = false;
    let delay = 200;

    this.timer = setTimeout(() => {
      if(!this.preventSimpleClick){
        //whatever you want with simple click go here
        console.log("simple click");
      }
    }, delay);

  }

  doubleClickFunction(): void{
    this.preventSimpleClick = true;
    clearTimeout(this.timer);
    //whatever you want with double click go here
    console.log("double click");
  }
```

Comment: Could the one who downvoted the question please explain why ?

Comment: I'm not the one who downvoted, but I guess it's because your answer doesn't add  anything to the other answers and also because it's not addressing the major issue of multi platform compatibility. But again, it's just a guess.

Comment: The answer has been upvoted by others. So the answer is useful for others

Answer (score 1):

So.

1. `dbclick` isn't working on smartphone.
2. Using a library is actually the way to go

*I found the solution on [this gitHub repo](https://github.com/Nykz/ionic6-angular-gestures)*

#### Directive

```js
import { Directive, EventEmitter, Output, OnInit, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appTap]'
})
export class TapDirective implements OnInit {

  @Output() tap = new EventEmitter();
  @Output() doubleTap = new EventEmitter();
  lastTap = 0;
  tapCount = 0;
  tapTimeout = null;
  tapGesture = {
    name: 'tap',
    enabled: false,
    interval: 250,
  };
  doubleTapGesture = {
    name: 'doubleTap',
    enabled: false,
    interval: 300,
  };

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.tapGesture.enabled = true;
    this.doubleTapGesture.enabled = true;
  }

  @HostListener('click', ['$event'])
  handleTaps(e) {
    const tapTimestamp = Math.floor(e.timeStamp);
    const isDoubleTap = this.lastTap + this.tapGesture.interval > tapTimestamp;
    if (!this.tapGesture.enabled && !this.doubleTapGesture.enabled) {
      return this.resetTaps();
    }
    this.tapCount++;
    if (isDoubleTap && this.doubleTapGesture.enabled) {
      this.emitTaps();
    } else if (!isDoubleTap) {
      this.tapTimeout = setTimeout(() => this.emitTaps(), this.tapGesture.interval);
    }
    this.lastTap = tapTimestamp;
  }

  private emitTaps() {
    if (this.tapCount === 1 && this.tapGesture.enabled) {
      this.tap.emit();
    } else if (this.tapCount === 2 && this.doubleTapGesture.enabled) {
      this.doubleTap.emit();
    }
    this.resetTaps();
  }

  private resetTaps() {
    clearTimeout(this.tapTimeout); // clear the old timeout
    this.tapCount = 0;
    this.tapTimeout = null;
    this.lastTap = 0;
  }

}
```

#### Module

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { TapDirective } from './tap/tap.directive';
import { PressDirective } from './press/press.directive';
import { SwipeDirective } from './swipe/swipe.directive';
import { GestureDirective } from './gesture/gesture.directive';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    TapDirective,
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
  exports: [
    TapDirective,
  ]
})
export class TapDirectiveModule { }
```

```html
<div appTap (doubleTap)="doSomething()"
```

There you go..

*Tips: I did let the `tap` logic, remove it if not needed*

Comment: This is pretty good. One thing, it could be improved by adding `@Input() mobileOnly: 'true' | 'false' | boolean = false;`, and a check if `Event instanceof PointerEvent` :)

Answer (score 0):

Ionic 2 has basic gestures which can be accessed from HTML.
Should work on iOS and Android.
You can find the [documentation here](http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#gestures).

The source code provided by them [is here](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-preview-app/tree/master/src/pages/gestures/basic).

Comment: The link to gestures is now here: https://ionicframework.com/docs/utilities/gestures

Answer (score 0):

For capturing generic gesture, I created the following to handle double click, long press and short swipe and release.

Make sure to import the GestureController from Ionic Angular

```
longPressStartedTime;

constructor(
        private gestureController: GestureController,
        ) { }
```

Create a class on the elements we want to attach the gesture handling to

```
<div class="long-pressable">
some content here...
</div>
```

Then create the gesture handling code handler

```
   let pressableElements = this.elementRef.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('.long-pressable') as any[];

    for(let i = 0; i < pressableElements.length; i++) {
      const gesture = this.gestureController.create({
        el: pressableElements[i],
        gestureName: 'long-press',
        threshold: 0,
        onStart: ev => {

          // double click
          if(this.longPressStartedTime && ((new Date().getTime() - this.longPressStartedTime) < 300)) {
            this.doubleClickMessage(this.chatMessages[i]);
          }
          this.longPressStartedTime = new Date().getTime();
          console.log("start")
        },
        onMove: ev => {
          //console.log("move", ev);
          if(ev.deltaX > 0 && ev.deltaX < 40) {
            pressableElements[i].style.transform = `translateX(${ev.deltaX}px)`;
          }
        },        
        onEnd: ev => {
          let longPressEllapsed = new Date().getTime() - this.longPressStartedTime;
          console.log("long press ended", longPressEllapsed)
          pressableElements[i].style.transform = `translateX(0px)`;

          if(ev.deltaX > 30) {
            this.handleSwipe(this.chatMessages[i]);
          }
          else if(longPressEllapsed > 500) {
this.handleLongPress()
          }
        }
      });
      gesture.enable(true);
      pressableElements[i].addEventListener('contextmenu', (evt) => {evt.preventDefault()});
    }
```